# Getting a list of files in order of the last 10 characters

Tags: c#, .net

I wish to sort my files in order of the last 10 characters of the filename, and I would like to do it in one instruction.

```
// this works

string s = "...blabla20140129.u", s2 = s.Substring(s.Length - 10,8);

// this fails with the message
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles(fileSpec).OrderBy(f => f.FullName.Substring(f.FullName.Length - 10),8);

Error   1   The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>, System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

It must be solved using .net 3.5 or less

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've simply got your brackets in the wrong place:

```
.OrderBy(f => f.FullName.Substring(f.FullName.Length - 10, 8));
```